# Transparent wxPanel member in wxFrame

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a MainFrame which is derived from `wxFrame`. The frame has a panel member `m_panel` of a custom class, derived from `wxPanel`.

I overloaded the `OnPaint()` function of the MainFrame to set a background image.

From the background image I only see a 5 pixel boarder. The rest is blocked by the wxPanel. And for some reason I cannot make the panel transparent. I tried `m_panel->Hide()` which had no effect at all and `m_panel->SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_CUSTOM)`. The latter had the weird effect that I could see the desktop (however the background image was still visible in the 5px border).

I did add the `wxTRANSPARENT_WINDOW` style in the constructor of the `wxPanel`.

How can I have this panel and make it transparent?

Comment: Why not paint on the panel?

Answer (score 1):

Have a custom `wxPanel` where you override `OnPaint` to have your drawings. Then use this as the main panel of your `wxFrame`. Example shown below:

```
class BackgroundPanel: public wxPanel
{
public:
    BackgroundPanel(wxFrame* parent);    
    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent & evt);

private:
    wxBitmap    backgroundBitmap;

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};


BackgroundPanel::BackgroundPanel(wxFrame* parent)
:wxPanel(parent)
{
    //Set backgroundBitmap
}


void BackgroundPanel::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& evt)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    int height = GetClientRect().GetHeight() - backgroundBitmap.GetHeight();
    dc.DrawBitmap(backgroundBitmap,0,height,false);
}
```